# How to check which web server you are running Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webserver, webrick, puma

I know this is probably very easy but I am having an overly hard time finding an answer. How do you check what web server your app is running in production?

I just switched from WEBrick to Puma (for production) and want to double check it is in fact using Puma. I am assuming it is as simple as a command? Any help would be much appreciated.

I am on Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Rails related question. You can invoke `ps aux` to list all running processes. I often invoke `top -d1 -c` command and sort by memory usage. Rails processes are usually on the top. From there you can see which services are running and how well are they performing.

You probably need to ask this question to great linux experts to get more detailed answer.